# Viewing a data matrix in Eclipse (RCP)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

This is how I update my TableViewer that displays a list:

```java
public void view(MyListClass list) {
    ViewerSupport.bind(
        this,
        new WritableList(list, controller.theClass()),
        BeanProperties.values(controller.theClass(), controller.strings())
    );
}
```

`controller` is an instance of a class that encapsulates my glue code (it is a different class for the two listings; as is `controller.theClass()`). `strings()` is an array of property names. MyListClass descends from `ArrayList<MyListEntryObject>`. That works fine. But, I want to display a matrix of data. `MyMatrixClass` is a `HashMap<Point, MyMatrixEntryObject>`. This is what I've tried:

```java
private void view(MyMatrixClass matrix) {
    columns(matrix.columns());

    List<WritableList> lists = new ArrayList<WritableList>(matrix.rows());

    for (MyEntityClass list : matrix.children())
        if (list instanceof MyListClass)
            lists.add(new WritableList((MyListClass) list, controller.theClass()));

    WritableList[] alists = lists.toArray(new WritableList[0]);

    MultiList mlist = new MultiList(alists);

    ViewerSupport.bind(
            this,
            mlist,
            BeanProperties.value(controller.theClass(), "value")
    );
}
```

This doesn't work. I get null argument popup errors. (Every data model class implements `MyEntityClass`. Class names have been altered due to this being a proprietary program I'm being employed to develop.)

Long story short, how do I use `ViewerSupport` and `BeanProperties` to display a matrix of data in a `TableViewer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the JFace table viewer is line-based, you have to provide your matrix in a line-based way. You have to create a collection of the lines of the matrix, and then set this list as the input of the viewer. After that, you could create BeanProperties, that display the columns of the selected rows.

Comment: That's why I was using `MultiList`. I figured that I might be able to push in each row as a `WritableList`. Obviously, that didn't work. What is `MultiList` for anyways?
At one point I had a class, `MyMatrixRow`, but I didn't know how to use that effectively. Each row has an arbitrary number of entries -> arbitrary number of properties. Then how do I avoid needing to write  a ton of `getValue1`, `getValue2`, etc?

Comment: Sadly, I don't know, how to solve your problem using Databinding. However, you could define your own content and labelproviders, that could take advantage of your datamodel - however, in this case, you are responsible for updating the display when the underlying model elements are changed.